# Build queue - missing assembly references vs2013

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, tfs, build

Two months ago we migrated TFS 2010 to TFS 2013. 
So we migrated our tests, and builds to new one. 
Right after migrating we try to make new build and we sucessed.

Now we have VS2013 and all *sln migrated to vs 2013.
Well Today im trying to do build but i got issues while creating builds.
After steps (bellow) i got this message, like all reference missing and its come from testtools.

I see diferences from vs2010 and vs 2013. its 10 vs 12 version of that dll.
If i add that reference i got problem to build that dll.

In this case, i have 2618 error with missing reference...

**run.cs (7): The type or namespace name 'UITesting' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**
**UIMap.Designer.cs (21551): The type or namespace name 'WinButton' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

> Overall Build Process 00:00 Update Build Number 00:00 Create the Drop
>   Location 00:56  Run On Agent (reserved build agent TFS - Agent) 00:00
>   Delete Test Results Directory 00:00 Delete Binaries Directory 00:13
>   Delete Workspace 00:00 Delete Sources Directory 00:00 Create Workspace
>   This build wastes time and computer resources because your working
>   folders include the team projects (QA), which include a Drops folder.
>   You should cloak the Drops folders. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=269693. 00:38 Get Workspace

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a reference to the assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting which resides in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll which is part of Coded UI. Something that goes wrong quite often; is that since coded UI is part of the Team Suite in 2010, you should install the Premium or Ultimate version of Visual Studio 2013 (or Enterprise if you are using 2015) on the buildserver and have the .net version of the test project set to at least the .net 4.5.

Comment: Build server is on TFS server. Is this smart to install it on that machine ?

Comment: i've tryed change project to -net 4.5 but cannot build dll.   -->                Error 2339 The type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback' exists in both 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll'

Comment: This means that in the references, you now have two different versions of this dll references. Look at the versions and make sure you have only one version (12.0.*) of the dll's, and reference the specific dll's only once.

Comment: Already did. It is some differences between version, but u cannot change it just like that. Meanwhile i found solution. So i need to install same version at server where are the build agents.

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it.
Answer is to install Premium 2013 @ server where are the build agents.
After that, minor changes, 
like [image]
So i change true to false, so no specific version, only automatic what is on build agent.

i hope i help it. (help myself) :D